# How do I select which lines of code to show and which lines to hide?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Sometimes only 10 lines of 100 are relevant to the question/answer, the other  90 are setup.

Is there a way to hide 90 those in lines in the answer?

Comment: [I proposed a solution here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239502/can-i-call-out-different-parts-of-a-snippet). Maybe you can argue that's the same question but I guess I didn't think of that until after I posted it. Doh

Comment: I had proposed a solution [@MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214)

Answer (score 6):

The way to do this is just to include the 10 lines like you normally would.

Then in the Stack Snippet you place the full code. *So the 10 lines will appear twice in the markup. One time before the snippet starts, and one time in the snippet.*

Then make sure to check mark the box to hide the snippet by default, as shown below :

[image]

For a working example of this, see my answer that does just this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766128/jquery-css-creating-a-pulsating-heart/21766468#21766468)

Comment: not very D.R.Y.

Comment: The question title reads *"How do I select which lines of code to show and which lines to hide?"* - from the snippet. Currently there is no option for that. Copy pasting isn't a practical solution for larger amount of code...