# Can I call out different parts of a snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I often format answers something like

Do this

```
var a = b * c;
```

Then do this

```
log("the answer is " + a);
```

Is it possible to pull those lines separately out of a snippet of say 10 lines to include in the answer?

For example maybe the full snippet is

```
var log = function(msg) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextnode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(div);
};

var b = 12;
var c = 34;

var a = b * c;

log("the answer is " + a);
```

It might be really nice to be able to mark up the snippet and then insert it in parts into the answer like maybe the snippet might look like this

```
var log = function(msg) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextnode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(div);
};

var b = 12;
var c = 34;

<!-- snippet#abc -->
var a = b * c;

<!-- snippet#answer -->
log("the answer is " + a);

<!-- snippit#end -->
```

And the markdown might look something like

```
Do this

![snippit#abc]

Then do this

![snippit#answer]


...full snippet source down here...
```

Thoughts? Seems like it would be very D.R.Y. and less error prone. You wouldn't have to fix two places if you come back and make an edit to the code.

Comment: +1 for the concept of highlighting the most relevant parts of a snippet. This is a much better version of my request here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271762/add-a-run-option-next-to-show-for-hidden-snippets But I was going to repeat things; something like this is the better way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great idea. In case if that is an overkill, something simpler like:

```
     <!-- language: lang-js -->
        // code
     <!-- language: lang-js:break -->
```

Your explanation for the code above.

```
     <!-- language: lang-js:continue -->
        // rest of the code
     <!-- language: lang-html -->
```

---

will do, IMHO